# react failed to compile module "conversational-form"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to import this [conversational-form npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conversational-form) to my Create-React-App application and I've been getting compile errors on any attempts to do so.

Here is the exact error:

```
./~/conversational-form/dist/conversational-form.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'conversationalform' in '/Users/user/Desktop/app_name/node_modules/conversational-form/dist'
```

So far I've tried to import it like

```
import ConversationalForm from 'conversational-form';
```

or using an absolute path to the js file in the "dist" folder, or even just including that js file in my project, but there are always compile errors.

The module [is supposed to work with React](https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form/blob/master/docs/reactjs.html).

Any ideas what may be causing this? Is perhaps Create-React-App incompatible with this? Should I just include the JQuery plugin from that module instead? Thank you.

UPDATE: Module seems to have been fixed now, but I still get errors when trying to adapt the example to a Webpack/React/Component structure

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

componentDidMount(){
13 |    // add Conversational Form info
> 14 |  this.refs.name.setAttribute('cf-questions', "Your name?");
15 |    this.refs.email.setAttribute('cf-questions', "Your email?");
16 |    this.refs.description.setAttribute('cf-questions', "What is description?");
```

---

CODE

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
    import ConversationalForm from './conversational_form';

    class ConversationForm extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.cf = null; // <-- Conversational Form ref
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            // add Conversational Form info
            this.refs.name.setAttribute('cf-questions', "Your name?");
            this.refs.email.setAttribute('cf-questions', "Your email?");
            this.refs.description.setAttribute('cf-questions', "What is description?");
            this.cf = window.cf.ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
                formEl: this.refs.form,
                context: document.getElementById("cf-context"),
                    flowStepCallback: function(dto, success, error){
                        success();
                    },
                    submitCallback: function(){
                    // this callback could also be added to the React.createElement it self...
                        alert("You made it!")
                        console.log("Form submitted...");
                    }
            });
        }
        render() {

            var conversation;

            if (this.props.visible) {
            conversation = 
            <div>
                    <form id="form" ref={form => this.input = form} className="form">
                        <input type="text" ref={name => this.input = name} placeholder="Name (required)" defaultValue={this.props.name} />
                        <input type="email" ref={email => this.input = email} placeholder="Email" defaultValue={this.props.email} />
                        <textarea ref={description => this.input = description} placeholder="Description" defaultValue={this.props.description} />
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <section id="cf-context" role="cf-context" cf-context>

                    </section>
                </div>
            }

            return (
                <CSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="success"
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
                {conversation}
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
            )
        }
    }

    export default ConversationForm;
```

Comment: Don't you want a react-conversational-form module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The reason for the error is likely the way you are using your import. Since `ConversationForm` is probably one of several components in the module
you need to import it like this:</s>

```
import {ConversationForm} from 'react-conversational-form';
```

---EDIT---

This is wrong, it seems like there is something fishy going on with the module itself.

---UPDATE---

The guys behind the module are super good and already issued a fix. The problem seemed to be with the way webpack handles dependencies. Now the module works as expected:

```
import cf from 'conversational-form'

var myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
var c = new cf.startTheConversation({formEl: myForm})
```

Comment: I just took a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-conversational-form, if that's what you mean, it looks empty and somehow not related to the module I linked?

Comment: You are right, it's empty :/ In any case it seems like the problem you are having is with the import. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I tried to import it like you suggested, import { ConversationalForm } from 'conversational-form' and that did not do the trick. The module is supposed to work with React. See https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form/blob/master/docs/reactjs.html

Comment: I think you are importing it right afterall, and it seems like there is something funny going on with the module. If you look into the module source file (the very bottom) you can see lines `define(["conversationalform"], function(conversationalform){` and `module.exports = (root.conversationalform = factory(require("conversationalform")));` If you replace (strings only!) with dash versions ("conversation-form") the resolving error goes away. However I still had troubles getting it to work. Perhaps worth importing via CDN?

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to look into this. There is definitely something odd going on with the module. I wanted to look into importing it via the CDN, but how do I import an external script into a React component?

Comment: From here https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form/blob/master/docs/reactjs.html (line 98 eg) it looks like it's available via `window.cf`.

Comment: It imports the library from a <script> tag though. My React components are separated and bundled via Webpack. That's why I'm struggling into importing it via CDN

Comment: I don't know how your app is structured but if you created the app with create-react-app I think you should have public folder with `index.html`. Putting the script tag there should make `window.cf` accessible from wherever.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the script doesn't work either. I'm not sure if it's my React acting up or the module is just failing. I will give up on this. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No worries, sorry couldn't help. For what it's worth I filed an issue here https://github.com/space10-community/conversational-form/issues/151 if you want to follow it.

Comment: @Doge check this out, if you reinstall the module through npm it should work now.

Comment: Thank you, I followed the thread closely and it seems the importing is fixed now. But I think I'll give up with it anyways, as I'm getting another error now. Perhaps it just simply does not like Webpack. I have updated my question with the new issue.

Comment: That error seems to be unrelated to the module. I'd suggest you close this question and open a new one.